# django no module name 'config'

Tags: python, django

I wrote these apps using Python 2 and now am using Python 3.

I've tried:

1. Changing to a new virtualenv and reinstalling requirements
2. `pip install config` -> returns a new Syntax error in an Exception...
3. `pip install django-config`

When running: `python3 manage.py runserver`
I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem and to get it to work I had to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to be the path to my settings.py file

> export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_name.settings

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to @PetarP:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # user-defined
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',

    # default
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
    # no 'django.contrib.sites'
]
```

as you can find this at `/blog/apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'
```

Answer (score 1):

After you create your module app with `python manage.py startapp test_app`, you should go into `settings.py` and register the app into

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Register your custom app here
    'test_app',
]
```

You should read the official [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) everything will be explained there.

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error when copying or cloning my project directory.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ''
```

Creating a new venv wasn't enough for me. I had to delete the old one first, not sure why.

Followed by these commands it worked like a charm after

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: In general try to be specific on how an answer applies to the original question. From your post and the fact that the error in the original post and the error you are getting do not appear to be the same it is not clear how they are both related

Comment: Don't get caught up in the extra error text, it's misleading.  Look at the actual error message which is the last line posted in the original message. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ''    I experienced the same error and I provided the steps I found to resolve the issue.  For an unknown reason, simply creating a new venv was not enough... my code only started working after I removed the original venv from the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your `setting.py`, change:

```
from config import db_host, db_database, db_password, db_username, db_port
```

To:

```
from .config import db_host, db_database, db_password, db_username, db_port
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after reinstalling a working repo onto a new machine. Turned out to be caused by PYTHONPATH, which was unset on the new machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chat_room'
```

Every time I create a new virtual environment and run `python -m django` I got the same warning.
This warning is due to the fact that I set some environment variables for my old app which has the `chat_room module`. so every time my new virtual environment uses my environment variable set in my .bash_profile instead of the default one in the new Django setting.
In the end, after getting rid of that environment variable `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=chat_room.settings` in my `.bash_profile` everything went ok.

Answer (score 0):

If using PyCharm, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable should be set to project_name.settings. This may be done in Edit Configurations -> Environment variables. See on pic:
[image: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable configuration to avoid error]

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
django.config.urls
```

to:

```
django.conf.urls
```